# Porque me devuelve valor cero?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, herencia

en mi clase de programación en un `form` tengo que mostrar en un mensaje el área, solo que quieren que lo datos de `height` y `width` los obtenga de la herencia de la clase y de la manera que lo estoy realizando siempre me devuelve cero en el valor del area

**DEMOSTRACION DEL CODIGO**

///CLASE RECTANGULO

```
class Rectangulo : PresentationObject
{
    public int resultadoArea;
    public int ResultadoArea
    {
        get
        {
            return this.resultadoArea;
        }

        set
        {
            this.resultadoArea = value;
        }

    }

    public Rectangulo()
    {
        this.ResultadoArea = width * height;         
    }   
}

//CLASE PRESENTATION OBJECT
class PresentationObject
    {
        public int width;
        public int height;    

        public int Width
        {
            get
            {                 
                 return this.width;                 
            }

            set
            {
                this.width = value;                    
            }


        }

        public int Height
        {
            get
            {
                return this.height;
            }

            set
            {    
                this.height = value; 
            }    
        }


        public PresentationObject()
        {

        }

        public PresentationObject(int width,int height)
        {
            this.Width = width;
            this.Height = height;                
        }
    }

///BOTON DONDE MUESTRA EL MENSAJE

    private void btbCalcular_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Rectangulo rect = new Rectangulo();
            MessageBox.Show("El area es: " + rect.resultadoArea , "Calcular Area", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
```

Comment: Tu constructor de la clase parámetro calcula el área cuando lo creas, pero no le pasas ni el alto ni el ancho del rectángulo. Cambia el constructor para que acepte las dimensiones y al crear el rectángulo indica cuanto mide y ya está solucionado

Comment: cual constructor edito?

Comment: Tienes que cambiar public Rectangulo() por public Rectangulo(int alt, int anch), lo que no me queda del todo claro para que utilizas la clase PresentationObject.Para utilizarla, deberías incluir en Rectángulo un objeto PresentationObject para guardar el ancho y alto, pero paso a paso

Comment: Se refiere al constructor de la clase Rectangulo. Ten en cuenta que, tal y como lo tienes, cuando creas una nueva instancia de Rectangulo() no tienes asignado en ningún sitio el height y el width. De ahí que el área sea 0 (debugeando lo puedes ver fácilmente).

Answer (score 5):

Se podrían hacer varios cambios pero ajustándome a tu código tienes que tener en cuenta las siguientes cosas:

- Tal y como lo tienes, cuando instancias la clase `Rectangulo` con `Rectangulo rect = new Rectangulo();` los valores de `height` y `width` son cero ya que no los has inicializado en ninguna parte, de ahí que el resultado de `this.ResultadoArea = width * height;` del constructor de la clase `Rectangulo` sea cero
- Los constructores de `PresentationObject` ahora mismo no tienen mucho sentido ya que no los estás usando

  ```
  public PresentationObject(int width, int height)
  {
      this.Width = width;
      this.Height = height;
  }
  ```

Si quieres usarlos tendrías que llamarles en el constructor de la clase `Rectangulo` a través de `base`:

```
    public Rectangulo(int wid, int hei):base(wid, hei)
    {
    }
```

Y cuando instancias la clase pasárselos como parámetros así:

```
Rectangulo rect = new Rectangulo(23,54);
```

De esta forma los parámetros "llegan" al constructor de `PresentationObject` y le asigna los valores a `Width` y `Height` para que puedan ser usados por la clase `Rectangulo` que hereda de `PresentationObject`

- Por último, para calcular el área lo mejor es crearse un método `CalcularArea()` en tu clase `Rectangulo` que asigne el valor de `width * height` a `ResultadoArea`

.

```
public void CalcularArea(){
    ResultadoArea = width * height;
    }
```

Y luego llamarle así:

```
Rectangulo rect = new Rectangulo(23,54);
rect.CalcularArea();
MessageBox.Show("El area es: " + rect.resultadoArea , "Calcular Area", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
```

No sé si me he terminado de explicar bien. ¡Mucho ánimo con esas lecciones! :)

Answer (score 5):

Tienes un problema de concepto, algo normal si estás empezando en POO.

Tu clase `Rectangulo` hereda de `PresentationObject`, con lo que hereda sus propiedades.

Cuando creas un objeto de tipo `Rectangulo`, lo que haces es crear una instancia de ese tipo, y esa instancia tiene varias propiedades: las propias (`ResultadoArea`) y las heredadas (`Width` y `Height`). Pero para esa instancia en concreto, dichas propiedades no tienen valor ya que tu no se lo has dado.

Vamos a tu código. Por un lado, en la clase `PresentationObject` las variables `width` y `height` deben ser privadas. El acceso a dichas variables se debe hacer usando las propiedades (`Width` y `Height`):

```
class PresentationObject
{
    private int width;
    private int height;    
    ...
```

Por otro lado, no es necesario el constructor de `PresentationObject` que recibe los parámetros `width` y `height` (aunque tampoco hace ningun daño tenerlo).

Por último, lo que debes hacer es cambiar el constructor de la clase `Rectangulo` para que puedas inicializar las propiedades necesarias para el cálculo:

```
public Rectangulo(int width, int height)
{
    // inicializamos las propiedades Width y Height que no forman parte de esta clase, 
    // sino que son heredadas de PresentationObject
    this.Width = width; 
    this.Height = height;
    // Ahora ya podemos calcular el area
    this.ResultadoArea = this.Width * this.Height;
}
```

La forma de usarlo sería la siguiente:

```
Rectangulo rect = new Rectangulo(30,50);
MessageBox.Show("El area es: " + rect.resultadoArea, "Calcular Area", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
```

Espero que con esta explicación te hayan quedado mas claros los conceptos que hay en juego en este problema. Si no es asi, no dudes en preguntar.